# What is the proper way to require node modules within next.js /api function handler

Tags: webpack, next.js, serverless, bcrypt

I am trying to require bcrypt inside a file within my /api folder.

```
// pages/api/login.js
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  switch (req.method) {
    case 'POST':
      // do stuff with bcrypt
      res.status(200).json()
      break
    default:
      res.status(405).end() //Method Not Allowed
      break
  }
}
```

Everything works fine when I use **npm run dev** but when I run **npx serverless** I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mock-aws-s3'
```

After a lot of research it seems this is happening because webpack is trying to include bcrypt in the client-side bundle when it should only be included in the server-side. I don't understand why this happens because according to the Next.js docs:

```
Any file inside the folder pages/api is mapped to /api/* and will be treated as an API endpoint instead of a page. They are server-side only bundles and won't increase your client-side bundle size.
```

I found a workaround to this problem by using eval

```
const bcrypt = eval("require('bcrypt')");
```

but this feels very hacky and like I am not understanding next.js properly. What is the proper way to handle this situation and why is webpack trying to include the files within /api?

Comment: have you tried to add mock-aws-s3 to package.json?

Comment: I don't think mock-aws-s3 is the problem. The problem is the client bundle is trying to include server-side node modules. The problem is similar to this but I couldnt get the solutions discussed in this post to work for my project. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/16618

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this problem earlier, make sure that you include both `node_modules` folder and `package.json` files in your serverless config file. If you exclude either one of them, it will throw the above mentioned error.

EDIT:
@tarandeept
Here is a screenshot of my packages:

[image]

And here is my folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you post an example of your serverless config file? I tried doing something similar as discussed in this thread but it didn't work. https://forum.serverless.com/t/package-excludes-do-not-seem-to-work/2314/3

Comment: Can you explain and give configurations. I try above method  it did not work